# Access Violation Exception when using vectors in a Windows Form

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++

**Update:**
In the debug solution I created I changed all my classes to managed classes just to see if it changed anything. When I did so the error changed to a `NullReferneceException`which makes me think that I am not initializing my classes before calling them.

**Update 2**
Having done some more digging it appears to me that my classes are being initialized, built, then discarded while the form is constructed. However this does not make sense, since I'm able to access all the way to my `CountryList` object before problems occur. But in short I believe the problem has to do with my form itself.

**Background**

I'm creating a project in which I display a bunch of information using a fairly simple windows form. The information being displayed consists of integers stored in custom classes created behind the scenes of the form itself, and is displayed in labels on the form. One of my custom classes `CountryList` has a vector of 84 pointers to `Country`s, my class which contains the data I wish to display.

My `CountryList` class is initialized within a third class called `Gamestate`, which is responsible for handling all the back-end logic of my program. It is my only class that directly interacts with my form.

**Problem**

When I try and access a `Country` from my `CountryList` at runtime to dynamically change what's displayed on my form I get the following error:

> **AccessViolationException was unhandeled**
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The error opens the file for the `vector` class and specifically triggers at the `size()` function. The call stack reads as follows:

- Foo.exe!std::vector >::size() Line 1179
- Foo.exe!std::vector >::at(unsigned __int64 _Pos) Line 1206 + 0x9 bytes
- Foo.exe!CountryList::get_country(int x) Line 20 + 0xf bytes
- Foo.exe!Foo::MyForm::button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) Line 78 + 0x27 bytes
- [External Code]
- Foo.exe!Main(array ^ args) Line 15 + 0x9 bytes

**Code**

Here is code to a debug version I made to be a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, while keeping it as close to the original project as possible.

Country.h

```
#pragma once
class Country
{
public:
    Country(int x);
    int get_bar();
private:
    int bar;
};
```

Country.cpp

```
#include "Country.h"

Country::Country(int x)
{
    bar = x;
}

int Country::get_bar()
{
    return this->bar;
}
```

CountryList.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Country.h"

class CountryList
{
public:
    CountryList();
    Country* get_country(int x);
private:
    std::vector<Country> countries;
};
```

CountryList.cpp

```
#include "CountryList.h"

CountryList::CountryList()
{
    countries.reserve(3);

    Country a(1);
    this->countries.push_back(a);

    Country b(2);
    this->countries.push_back(b);

    Country c(3);
    this->countries.push_back(c);
}

Country* CountryList::get_country(int x)
{
    return &this->countries.at(x);
}
```

Gamestate.h

```
#pragma once
#include "CountryList.h"

class Gamestate
{
public:
    Gamestate();
    CountryList* countryLst;
};
```

Gamestate.cpp

```
#include "Gamestate.h"

Gamestate::Gamestate()
{
    CountryList* countryLst = new CountryList();
}
```

MyForm.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Gamestate.h"

namespace Foo {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected:
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: Gamestate* game = new Gamestate();
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected:

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(39, 39);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"label";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(114, 34);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 74);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

//problem occurs when this event is triggered
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        this->button1->Text = System::Convert::ToString(this->game->countryLst->get_country(1)->get_bar());
    }
    };
}
```

MyForm.cpp

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Foo::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Any assistance you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Too much information. Can you try reducing your question to a [mcve].

Comment: Can you reduce that to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `std::vector<Country*> countries;` -- You were doing so well with `vector`, and then for some strange reason, you resorted to using a vector of pointers.  Why?  What was wrong with doing the obvious `std::vector<Country> countries;`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  - I originally had it as just a vector of countries, but I was getting the same error. Changing it to a vector of pointers was an attempt at fixing the issue.

Comment: @TrikkStar  When you changed to pointers, you made the problem worse.  You shouldn't throw stuff on the wall and hope something sticks.  There is nothing wrong with `std::vector<Country>`, rather, it eliminates it from the list of candidates that may have caused the problem.  All members of `Country` are safely copyable and assignable with no issues.  On the other hand, a `std::vector<Country*>` automatically puts your code at risk if a `GameState` is copied or assigned anywhere.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Ok, I'll go back and change it to a vector of `Country`s. I had thought that pointers could introduce additional problems but wasn't entirely sure if using them was a bad idea or not.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is that a more concise example of the problem?

Comment: @RSahu Same thing, Is the new core I provided a more concise example of the problem I'm experiencing?

Comment: Well, whatever the language this is, it looks very similar to C++, but this is not C++ that I know. Never seen the bizarre "array<String^>^" declaration in MyForm.cpp, before. Must be Microsoft's non-standard extensions to C++. The shown code is a bit too big, but wouldn't normally preclude a quick cut-n-paste, and a run through the compiler and debugger. However, since I only use a standards-compliant C++ compiler, that does not understand Microsoft's own languages, I can't be much help here. I'm sure Microsoft dev. tools offer extensive debugging features that can debug this, like gdb.